# Wcf services and Db settings?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, design-patterns, .net-4.0

I was asked to build different `WCF` services where each do other work against sql.

We have *5* db's. All db's+connection string are in *1* xml file. ( file-system file)

The services are hosted under `WAS` iis 7.5.

since each service should read from db , each service references a `DAL dll` file.

So here are our components :

[image]

I would like to read the xml data to `CACHE` ( at the first request) and from now on - read from cache. (reading the file each reqeust is *out of the question*).

- idea #1  = the dll , in his ctor   , at first request will read the xml file and load it to **its** cache.

so the `dal` will look like this :

[image]

so now each service can access the DLL's cache object via property. ( one advantage is when dealing with `cache dependency` on a single file - so when it is changing    , we should reload only to *one* location).

- idea #2 = when service is up , load the xml into **its** `cache`.

so now , each service will look like this :

Service #1  :

[image]

Service #2  :

[image]

..

the downside is many cache dependencies on the same file

<kbd>Question :</kbd>

By the best practice experience and by design pattern *POV* : which is the preferred way ?

*p.s. the xml file change frequency 1/(1 month)*

Comment: Why use an external xml file, and not a .config file? Web.config is not physically read on every request either, and it would be trivial to use, wouldn't it?

Comment: @PabloRomeo writing in web.config means : 1) there will be [n] entries  ( duplicate) ....2) changing a value will restart the app.....3) there is no point on putting cache dependency on a web.config file.

Comment: Yes, I agree to all those, except maybe 1) since it would seem you'd have the same amount of entries, 5 ConnectionStrings either way.
But, from my experience connection strings are only usually changed during deployments, it's not something you'd probably change every other day. That's why I didn't think i'd be a problem. I usually go for the KIS approach first, unless requirements really call for physically independent services that aren't restarted when one of the 5 connStrings change.

Comment: @Blam _Why are connection strings changing once a month_ I don't know ask the company. also , if i can change the settings without restart - it is better. cache is my choice also. but where ? that is the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when it comes to file system, on Windows Server OS, there's a built in cache layer above the disk. So you probably won't feel much difference regarding disk reads. Of course, parsing the same input again and again is not a good practice, so the parsed (tokenized) xml should be cached.

The design needs more clarifications:

1. Is there only a single instance of a DAL class, shared among the 5
   services? Or maybe the property described in idea 1 is static?
2. In idea 2: when the file changes and, say, connection string 4 is
   changed (and everything else remains the same) - only service 4
   should be reloaded?
3. If a specific service is reloaded - does it cause some kind of
   inconsistency with other (non fresh) services?

Update:

I'm still not sure I fully understand the scenario, but here's what I'd do as far as I understand:

The DAL should expose an interface for all data related operations.

Let's say it's `IDataGateway`

Now, each service has should have a reference to an instance that implements `IDataGateway`. The service should not be aware of the caching mechanism at all. It just consumes data from the interface.

So all of the caching is done outside the service, in terms of classes and code organization.

Now, the caching layer, in turn, implements `IDataGateway`, and also consumes a non cached instance of `IDataGateway`. That's called *Decorator* pattern. The non cached instance is to be injected in the constructor.

Now, I suggest each service has its own instance of a cached `IDataGateway`. It's simpler than a singleton (to me, at least). And since data is not shared between services, then we're cool. If, however, data **is** shared between the services, than a single instance should be used.

Back to those 5 instances, and to the xml file.

We want to monitor this file once it changes, right? We could easily write our own file monitor, or use the one that comes with the framework, or we could see the source code of the CacheDependency class.

The simplest way to do it is to have 5 monitors watching the same file. That's not much of a performance penalty, since timers are quite "cheap".

If, however, you'd like to reduce the resources being used by your system, then you could use a single monitor, having it raise its event of `FileChanged` or something like that. Each of the 5 cached implementations (those 5 instances) of `IDataGateway` should have this monitor injected in its constructor, and wire up its own event listener to the `FileChanged` event.
Once this event is triggered, all of the 5 cached instances of `IDataGateway` would invalidate their inner cache, thus they should clear their in-memory entries.

On the next call, the cached implementation of `IDataGateway` would try to take the non existing data from its in-memory cache, but obviously nothing would be there, so it should go on executing the same method in the non-cached implementation of `IDataGateway`, and populate its cache.

That's my design, HTH...

Comment: Hi @ron Thanks for answering. #1 ) DAL is a regular non static class which is referenced by those services. if I would choose solution 1 , so yes - there will be a static property which will allow all services access its cache.....#2) no. when the file changes , all [n] services should reload the cache ( if we choose solution 2). each service has cache file dependency.......#3)no. when service is reloaded - it is regarding only to its data.... and with what connection information  **he** should access db from no on.

Answer (score 0):

For me the question comes down to who really needs to know about connection strings: the DAL or the Service?  Obviously it's the DAL.  The service doesn't (or shouldn't) care what kind of data store the DAL is using - could be a bunch of CSV's on the disk (yikes!) for all it cares.  So, it wouldn't make sense to put the connection strings in the services.  The DAL needs the connection info, so the DAL should take care of finding it and caching it.